# Returning new base class when the parent class shared pointer is the return type

Tags: c++, pointers, shared, radix, derived

Can you have a parent class shared pointer return type of a function and then return a new child class without it being a shared pointer? I'm not sure how shared pointers work in these situations, do they act like a regular pointer? Here is my example:

```c++
BaseEventPtr Actions::getEvent(const std::string& nodeName)
{
    if(asLowerCaseString(nodeName) == "action")
        return new ActionEvent(&m_interface);

    return nullptr;
}
```

ActionEvent is the subclass of BaseEvent in this situation.

Cheers!

Comment: Ever heard of the [factory pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5120768/796036)? Maybe this will give you some ideas what you really want.

Comment: Yea I have heard of it, will look into it for revamping the current systems I'm working on, Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `BaseEventPtr` is a smart pointer it should be OK.

Basically the shared pointer calls `delete` on the real pointer when there are no more references. If the base class has a **virtual destructor** defined, `delete` calls the proper subclass' destructor.

For example:

```
class NonVirtualBase {};
class NonVirtualSubclass: public NonVirtualBase {};

shared_ptr<NonVirtualBase> ptr( new NonVirtualSubclass() ); // NOT OK!

class VirtualBase
{
    virtual ~VirtualBase() {}
};

class VirtualSubclass: public VirtualBase {};

shared_ptr<VirtualBase> ptr( new VirtualSubclass() ); // OK
```

This applies to normal (naked) pointers as well. That's why as a general rule, if a class may serve as a base class in the future, it should be defined with a virtual destructor (even if empty).