# reuse factory type constructor in subclass

Tags: c++, factory, copy-constructor

Sorry I'm pretty green with C++ is this sort of thing possible?

I have a superclass that has a huge constructor so I made a static factory type constructor that will do some work and then return new ParametricShape(blah blah blah...);

```
class ParametricShape: public ModelView{

public:
    //actually has 15 arguments didn't want to type them all up
    ParametricShape(func x, funcy, funcz, float lu, float hu, float lv, float hv, int sv, int su);

     static ParametricShape* makeDonutShape(float);
 }
```

Later I want to use this static method in an extended class.

```
class Donut : public ParametricShape{
    Donut();
}

Donut::Donut(){
  this = ParametricShape::makeDonut(1.0f);
}
```

This is the sort of thing I'm trying to do, I've been fumbling around with various copy constructors and what not and been getting all sorts of different errors. Currently it just says: lvalue requried as left operand of assignment.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: *Why* did you want that? That makes no sense...?!

Comment: You can't modify the `this` pointer. Instead, rewrite the "make..." methods: They should not return a new instance but modify an existing instance. Also, I think you don't want to override the shape class in your case since you don't introduce any new members but only provide creation routines for parametric functions

Comment: @KerrekSB because I want to extend parametric shape to always look like a donut and override some other stuff in rendering,etc I'm pretty limited on what I can do because I'm given a modelview class with prive/protected stuff that I'm not allowed to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with most of the other answers, in your case you don't need the classical factory pattern. As I can see, you want to have a single class which describes a shape with parametric functions for their geometry. You want to provide convenience methods to create those shapes for some special cases, like the "donut". As long as you don't want to make use of any other inheritance features like overloading some methods for special shape types, you can simply drop your other classes like `Donut` and just use the "maker" functions in your client code.

An option to make the code still look more object-oriented (and to keep the subclasses and use their constructors in the client code), you can rewrite the maker functions to initialization functions, as I want to call them. Note that I also introduced a default constructor which we need in the specialized classes:

```
class ParametricShape {
    func x, y, z;
    ...

public:
    ParametricShape();
    ParametricShape(func x, func y, func z, ...);

protected:
    void initDonutShape(float);
};


class Donut : public ParametricShape {

public:
    Donut(float radius) :
        ParametricShape()         // call default constructor of ParametricShape
    {
        initDonutShape(radius);   // initialize functions for "Donut"
    }
};
```

Now, implement the `initDonutShape` method like this:

```
void ParametricShape::initDonutShape(float radius) {
    // set the parametric functions
    x = ...
    y = ...
    z = ...
}
```

rather than returning a new instance of `ParametricShape`.

Comment: Overriding some of the render stuff is exactly what I'm trying to do here, I want it to always be translated a certain way and have a certain texture. Unfortunately this is for a school project and I've been provided with a modelview class I can't change and they made some of this stuff protected/private.  Good suggestion on the init functions I'm just going to go that route. Cheers!

Comment: @schwiz At the end, this method is very similar to yours, but with the most important change being done: In the constructor of the subclass, the `ParametricShape` instance has already been created (this is because of the inheritance; you can't avoid this). You should only modify this, not throw this away and recreate another one. However, you only need one subclass per special shape type if you want to treat them all differently (one overloaded render method for each type, for example).

Comment: One last note: You can also just initialize the parametric functions in the `Donut` constructor. You don't need the init functions at all. However, they are nice if you want to reuse them from type to type, for example to separate geometry from textures and to create a wooden donut + a metal donut. But in this case, give the init methods a meaningful name, e.g. "initDonutGeometry", "initWoodTexture", etc.

Comment: yeah the 'make' functions I have are each about 30+ lines of code so this is why I was avoiding just using the constructor again. I should have just gone the init route to begin with. Lesson learned!

Answer (score 2):

You can not assign to "this". It is a const type.

> [The type of the this pointer for a member function of a class type X,
>   is X* const.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr035.htm)

In the factory design pattern you usually have a separate class taking care of creating new instances. This separation of object creation from the class itslef is the whole point of this design pattern. [See this discussion on how to implement this in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120768/how-to-implement-the-factory-pattern-in-c-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the typical "factory" pattern:

```
#include <memory>

struct Shape
{
    enum Type { Donut, Sphere, Teapot };

    static std::unqiue_ptr<Shape> make(Type type);

    virtual ~Shape() = default;

    // ...
};

struct Donut : Shape
{
    // ...
};

std::unique_ptr<Shape> Shape::make(Shape::Type type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case Donut: return { new Donut; }
        default:    return { };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
auto p = Shape::make(Shape::Donut);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible... :)

```cpp
#include <new>
Donut::Donut() {
    this->~Donut();
    new (this) ( *((Donut*) ParametricShape::makeDonut(1.0f)) );
}
```

make sure you have a copy-constructor defined,
`this->~Donut();` ensures that everything allocated via default constuctors are deleted, and the second line `new (this) ( (Donut*) ParametricShape::makeDonut(1.0f) );` first creates a donut object, reinterprets it as Donut [be careful, this is problemless here because Donut does not define any variable more than it's parent] and calls a copy-constructor...

new (this) will not allocate any new storage from memory, it just calls the constructor :)

Comment: While being creative, this answer doesn't help very much as it leads to very bad code design. I'm sure your answer is ironic.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't call a destructor before the object is constructed. Also, I have a feeling that `makeDonut` already calls the constructor, which would lead to an infinite recursion.

Comment: No, Actually you can call the destructor. This is a usual pattern for constructor re-using prior to C++ 11. Also, according to the asked question, ParametricShape::makeDonut does not call Donut(), this is a rare place, which you don't want to change already designed code, but want to add extensions and create wrappers for a more clean API but dirty inside. This code, works!