# In this example from Effective C++ book, what are the implementation details for a function to return the object pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, object

```
class Investment { ... }; // root class of hierarchy of
                          // investment types

Investment* createInvestment(); // return ptr to dynamically allocated
                                // object in the Investment hierarchy;
                                // the caller must delete it
                                // (parameters omitted for simplicity)

void f()
{
Investment *pInv = createInvestment(); // call factory function
...                                    // use pInv
delete pInv;                           // release object
}
```

In the book, the author gives the example code like the one shown above. This is the first time I've seen this line:

```
Investment* createInvestment(); // call factory function
```

Is this function written inside the class definition or outside? What are the requirements in the class definition to make that line functional? i.e. Would you need a definition like this? Is this even a valid definition?

```
class Investment {
    public:
        Investment* createInvestment(){
            return ptr;
        };
    private:
        Investment* ptr;
};
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120768/how-to-implement-the-factory-method-pattern-in-c-correctly) may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for that article. So do you always create a new object inside the factory function?

Comment: `class Investment { ... }; Investment* createInvestment();` – seriously, it should be pretty clear that the function is **not** a member of the `Investment` class.

Comment: @niamleeson a factory function typically creates a new object and relinquishes ownership of the created object to the caller, yes. In other circumstances you could have a class that owns objects and returns non-owning pointers or references to those owned objects but I wouldn't call that a factory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this function written inside the class definition or outside?

It can be either. In this example it's outside the class in a free function. It could also be put inside a separate `InvestmentFactory` class. But it could also be put inside the `Investment` class, in which case it would need to be `static` (i.e. not tied to a specific `Investment`).

> What are the requirements in the class definition to make that line functional?

If the constructor of `Investment` is accessible from inside `createInvestment` (in this case, it would have to be public), then it could be as simple as

```
Investment* createInvestment() { return new Investment; }
```

But in your example there is a comment that `Investment` is the "root class of hierarchy of investment types". That means that the `createInvestment` method probably exists to create classes *derived* from `Investment`, and return an `Investment*` to allow for polymorphism. For example suppose `Stock` and `Bond` both derive from `Investment`; then `createInvestment` might look like this:

```
Investment* createInvestment(InvestmentType investType) {
    switch (investType) {
        case STOCK:
            return new Stock;
        case BOND:
            return new Bond;
        default:
            throw std::invalid_argument("investType");
    }
}
```

It's a rather silly example, but it just shows something that could work.

In your example:

> ```
> class Investment {
>     public:
>         Investment* createInvestment(){
>             return ptr;
>         };
>     private:
>         Investment* ptr;
> };
> ```

This is very wrong (although it will compile). First of all, there is no need for a class to store a pointer to itself (that's the `this` keyword). Second, you never initialize `ptr`, so your `createInvestment` will return an uninitialized pointer. You need a `new` somewhere to actually create an object.

Answer (score 2):

The factory function is a non-member function. I would expect it to take a parameter that specifies the type of `Investment` to create:

```
Investment* createInvestment(const std::string& type, int amount) {
    if(type == "stock") 
        return new Stock(amount);
    else
        return new Bond(amount);
}
```

where `Stock` and `Bond` are classes which derive from `Investment`.

The calling code is taking ownership of the `Investment` and must remember to call `delete` on it.  For this to work `Investment` must have a virtual destructor. It will probably have other virtual member functions to provide polymorphic behaviour and may be abstract.

```
class Investment {
public:
    virtual ~Investment(){}
    virtual int getAmount() const = 0;
};
```

The modern way of writing such a factory function is to return a`unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Investment> createInvestment(const std::string& type, int amount) {
    if(type == "stock") 
        return std::make_unique<Stock>(amount);
    else
        return std::make_unique<Bond>(amount);
}
```

Then you don't need to remember to call `delete`.

[Live demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gCsNMtPbF5COs0mo)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do have one more question; if you create a new object inside `createInvestment()`, shouldn't you delete them later? How would you go back and delete them?

Comment: @niamleeson Yes, Scott says as much in his comment. But not if you use `unique_ptr`. I'll try and make it more clear in my answer...

Comment: @niamleeson I'm not sure what you mean by "go back and delete them".  If the calling code calls `delete` on the created `Investment` and it has a virtual destructor then the `Stock` or `Bond` will be properly destroyed.