# rogue like game initializing error

Tags: c++, polymorphism, instance, dynamic-memory-allocation, roguelike

I'm making a simple map for simple rogue-like game.
So I need to initialize map with Objects created for each array cell by receiving data from character array[i][j].
Suggested that such CWall, CDoor classes are defined in other files like CWall.cpp, CWall.h, Underneath are the code to initialize in map.cpp

But is this right way to code?
I think this causes a problem of allocating memory.

```
CObject CMap::insertObject(char character){ 
    if (character = '*') {
        CWall cwall;
        return cwall;
    }

    if (character = 'D') {
        CDoor cdoor;
        return cdoor;
    }

    if (character = 'F') {
        CFood cfood;
        return cfood;
    }

    if (character = 'K') {
        CKey ckey;
        return ckey;
    }

    if (character = 'M') {
        CMMonster cmmonster;
        return cmmonster;
    }

    if (character = 'm') {
        CMonster cmonster;
        return cmonster;
    }

    if (character = '@') {
        CPlayer cplayer;
        return cplayer;
    }

    if (character = 'P') {
        CPrincess cprincess;
        return cprincess;
    }

    if (character = '&') {
        CRock crock;
        return crock;
    }

    if (character = 'S') {
        CShield cshield
        return cshield;
    }

    else {
        CShield cshield;
        return cshield;
    }
}

void CMap::initialize(char arr[][COLS]){
    for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <= 38; j++){
            char character = arr[i][j];
            insertObject(character);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed like you've mentioned. but it occurred additional question. Then what will be the return format like? will it be "return cwall;"?

Comment: `if (character =` should be `if (character ==`.

Comment: On a side note, you are unlikely to succeed with polymorphism here. There is nothing in common between Door and Princess - so there are no almost properties they can share together. You will end up constantly casting your objects and this is a nightmare.

Comment: This sounds like a job for `switch-case`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for one thing, you aren't actually initializing anything. `CWall* cwall = new CWall;` would be the proper way to dynamically allocate and initialize a new CWall object (assuming CWall has a default constructor, of course), or any object for that matter.

What you also need to bear in mind is that, for everything you allocate with `new`, you have to deallocate with `delete` later. Thus, you will need to put some thought into how you store those allocated objects, so you can ensure your destructor or cleanup function removes all of them when you're done. One design pattern to consider would be the [Object Pool](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html), though there are easily several dozen good ways to do it. That's footwork you're going to have to do yourself, though, as only you know enough about your project to select the right design pattern. (That book I linked to is a great resource.)

EDIT: As per your comment, there is one other issue, and that is that you are returning different types of objects. This is a simple issue of **inheritance** - as long as all of those objects inherit from an abstract base class of `CObject` (or something similar), you can simply list the return type as `CObject*`. Then, as long as you're returning an object (or a pointer to an object) that inherits from `CObject`, you're golden.

EDIT 2: Whenever you use `new`, you are actually getting a pointer to the dynamically allocated object. That creates some problems of its own, including that `new` can return a null pointer if the allocation fails. Be sure to check for that! A smart pointer can prevent many of those problems, but your use of smart pointers depends on your design pattern choices.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've changed like you've mentioned. but it occurred additional question. Then what will be the return format like? will it be "return cwall;"?

Comment: `new` returns a pointer, so `CWall cwall = new CWall;` is not correct.

Comment: So the format would be like this? CObject* CMap::insertObject(char character){ 
 if (character = '*') {
  CWall *cwall = new CWall;
  delete cwall;
  return cwall;
 }

Comment: One, backticks (`) are your friend, as they let you wrap your code in comments. Two...that looks mostly right, except A) You don't want to delete until you're done using the object entirely, and B), You may want to look into smart pointers, as I said. Doing this right will require a good deal of research on your part. (The other answers here have some good info too.)

Answer (score 3):

That's not the right way to do it. You are subject to [*object slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing), since my guess is that your `CObject` is an object and not a pointer to some object. You need to either return a pointer of type `CObject*` in your function, then for each case return a `new CMonster` or `new CPlayer` etc. Even better, use a smart pointer instead.

What you are trying to implement is called a *factory method pattern*, see e.g. [How to implement the factory method pattern in C++ correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120768/how-to-implement-the-factory-method-pattern-in-c-correctly) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

While others correctly pointed out how to code the idea you want coded, I will focus on another thing. Namely, improper usage of polymorphism here. Inheriting everything from meaningless Object smells like Java, and is not welcome in C++. There is simply nothing in common between Princess and Monster (one is kissed, another one is slayed, and to do what with which is up to one's taste), so when both are inherited from Object, it is extremely hard to program the proper game mechanic. You will have to store the actual object type as well (say, an enumeration), and than cast to this type - because only one of them will have method `kiss()` on them!

The whole code will be a spaghetti of unsafe casts and will be impossible to maintain or reason about.

Instead, go for stongly typed approach. Always know what type is in front of you!

Comment: Superb tips, Sergey. Inherit princess and monster from the same source, and you get a Damsel Of Distress. (Though, perhaps not a bad scenario if you want your Princess to attack...?) And walls don't attack anyway. Having different base classes also makes for easier coding, since all monsters have attack stats and strength, objects have enchantment level, etc.

Comment: TDTTOE - a player ought to be able to `kiss()` anything kissable, and the game should handle the result in a meaningful manner.

Answer (score 1):

You should be dealing with the data dynamically. What you're doing now has several problems.

A better approach would be:

```
CObject* CMap::insertObject(char character){ 
    if (character = '*') {
        return new CWall();
    }
...
```

This will utilize polymorphism to hide the actual class (such as `CWall`) behind the generic interface (`CObject`). As you wrote it, each "new" object, such as `cdoor`, would actually be passed to a copy constructor for `CObject`. None of which actually accomplished anything meaningful.

Of course, you need to pair these creations with proper destructions down the road.