# How to make objects in the deep easily configurable "from the top"?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, configuration, decoupling

Consider the following relation between classes:

```
int main(int, char**) { | class Window {      | class Layout { | class Box {
    /* Use argc/argv */ |     Layout layout;  |     Box box;   |     int height,
    Window window;      |                     |                |         max_width;
}                       |     bool print_fps; | public:        |
                        |                     |     Layout();  | public:
                        | public:             | };             |     Box (int,int);
                        |     Window ();      |                | };
                        | };                  |                |
```

<sup>I made up this structure just for simplicity, in reality there are many more classes.</sup>
In `main()` I fetch some application parameters (via configuration files, database, CLI arguments). Now I want to deliver those values to the desired objects.

My question: ***Which*** is *the best/most elegant* way to "break the wall" between the classes so that I can *"throw"* the configuration and whoever needs it to *"grab"* it?

---

**Initialy** I "opened some doors" and gave the `Window` constructor everything that was needed by `Window`, `Layout` and `Box`. Then, `Window` gave to `Layout` everything needed by `Layout` and `Box`. And so on.

I quickly realized this was very similar to what **Dependency Injection** it about but as it turns out, it does not apply directly to my case.
Here I work with *primitives* like `bool` and `int` and in fact if I accept them as constructor parameters, I get the result described just above - a very long chain of similar calls: `Window(box_height, box_max_width, window_print_fps)`.

What if I'd like to change the type of `Box::height` to `long`? I would need to walk *through every pair of header/source* of *every class* in the chain to change it.

If I want my classes to be isolated (*and I do*) then *Window* shouldn't worry about *Box* and *main* shouldn't worry about *Layout*.

---

Then, **my second idea** came up:  create some JSON-like structure which acts as a config object. Everybody gets a (shared) pointer to it and whenever they want, they say `this->config["box"]["height"]` - everyone's happy.

This would kinda work, but there are two problems here: *no type safety*
and *tight coupling* between a class (`Config`) and the *entire* code base.

---

Basically, I see **two ways around the problem**:

1. *"Downwards"*: **Out -> In**
   Objects on the top (**outer**) care about object in the deep (**inner**). They *push down* explicitly what inners want.
2. *"Upwards"*: **In <- Out** <sub>(the "diagram" is the same, but please wait)</sub>
   Objects on the bottom (**inner**) care about themselves on their own. They satisfy their needs by reaching out to some container on the top(**outer**) and *pull* what they want.

It's either *up* or *down* - I'm trying to think out of the box <sub>(In fact, it is a line - just ↑ or ↓)</sub> but I ended up only here.

---

**Another issue** arising from my two ideas earlier is about the way configuration is parsed:

1. If main.cpp (or the config parser) needs to give `int height` to `Box`, then it needs to know about box in order to parse the value properly, right? (tight-coupling)
2. If, on the other hand, main.cpp doesn't know about Box (ideally), how should it store the value in a friendly for the box way?
3. Optional parameters shouldn't be needed in constructors => shouldn't break the application. That is, main should accept the absence of some parameter, but it also needs to know that a setter has to be called for the desired object after it's been constructed with the required parameters.

---

**The whole idea** is to strive to these three principles:

1. Type safety. Provided by solution 1. but not 2.
2. Loose coupling. Provided neither by 1. (main cares about Box) nor by 2. (everybody needs Config)
3. Avoid duplication. Provided by 2 but not 1. (many identical parameters forwarded until they reach their target)

I implemented a sub-optimal solution I'll post as a self-answer, which works well for now and it's better than nothing but I'm looking forward for something better!

Comment: it would be nice if you could be a bit more specific and maybe add some more code. Eg. it is not clear how/when `Box` needs the parameters, is it default constructed and has setters? or do you need to pass the parameters in contructor? Your example is missing a way to set the parameters because they are private and the constructor takes no parameters

Comment: I usually prefer alternative 2. Combined with an observer pattern it allows all components to keep track of the configuration parameters they are interested in and enables them to react to configuration modifications during application execution. Don't quite get the type-safety concerns. If you let your component do `config->get<int>(height)` and whatever was read for 'height' is not convertible to an int you can just throw or return a default. There is a type-safety border somewhere anyway as long as you read your config from a text file.

Comment: @tobi303 Required deps are passed to the c-tor, and optional ones use setters.

Answer (score 1):

I am very much in favor of the second approach and hacked together a quick outline of an implementation. Please keep in mind that I am not claiming that this is the best solution, however, it is a solid one in my opinion. Interested to hear your comments and critics.

First, have some tiny objects, that represent a configurable value.

```
class ConfigurationParameterBase
{
public:
    ConfigurationParameterBase(ConfigurationService* service, 
        std::string name)       
        : service_(service), name_(std::move(name)) {
        assert(service_);
        service_->registerParameter(this);
    }
protected:
    ~ConfigurationParameterBase() {
        service_->unregisterParameter(this);   
    }

public:    
    std::string name() const { return name_; }
    virtual bool trySet(const std::string& s) = 0;

private:
    ConfigurationService* service_;
    std::string name_;
};

template<typename T>
class ConfigurationParameter : public ConfigurationParameterBase
{
public:
    ConfigurationParameter(ConfigurationService* service,
        std::string name, std::function<void(T)> updateCallback = {})
        : ConfigurationParameterBase(service, std::move(name))
        , value_(boost::none)
        , updateCallback_(std::move(updateCallback))
    { }

    bool isSet() const { return !!value_; }
    T get() const { return *value_; }
    T get(const T& _default) const { return isSet() ? get() : _default; }

    bool trySet(const std::string& s) override {
        if(!fromString<T>(s, value_))
            return false;            
        if(updateCallback_)
            updateCallback_(*value_);
        return true;
    }

private:
    boost::optional<T> value_;
    std::function<void(T)> updateCallback_;
};
```

Every object stores a value of any particular type (easily handled using a single class template) that represents a configuration parameter specified by its name. Furthermore, it holds an an optional callback that shall be invoked upon modification of the respective configuration. All instantiatons share a common base class, which registers and unregisters the class with the given name at a central `ConfigurationService` object. Beyond that, it forces derived classes to implement `trySet`, which reads a configuration value (string) into the type expected by the parameter. If this is successful, the value is stored and the callback invoked (if any).

Next, we have the `ConfigurationService`. It is responsible for keeping track of the current configuration and all the observers. Individual options can be set using `setConfigurationParameter`. Here we can add functions to read entire configurations from a file, a database, the network or whatever.

```
class ConfigurationService
{
public:
    void registerParameter(ConfigurationParameterBase* param) {
        // keep track of this observer
        params_.insert(param);
        // set current configuration value (if one exists)
        auto v = values_.find(param->name());
        if(v != values_.end())
             param->trySet(v->second);
    }

    void unregisterParameter(ConfigurationParameterBase* param) {
        params_.erase(param);
    }

    void setConfigurationParameter(const std::string& name, 
        const std::string& value) {
        // store setting
        values_[name] = value;
        // update all 'observers'
        for(auto& p : params_) {
            if(p->name() == name) {
                if(!p->trySet(value))
                    reportInvalidParameter(name, value);
            }
        }
    }

    void readConfigurationFromFile(const std::string& filename) {
        // read your file ...
        // and for each entry (n,v) do
        //    setConfigurationParameter(n, v);
    }

protected:
    void reportInvalidParameter(const std::string& name, 
        const std::string& value) {
        // report whatever ...
    }

private:
    std::set<ConfigurationParameterBase*> params_;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> values_;
};
```

We can then finally define the classes of our application. Every class member (of type `T`) that shall be configurable, is replaced by a member `ConfigurationParameter<T>` and initialized in the constructor with the respective configuration name, and - optionally - an update callback. The class can then make use of these values as if they were normal class members (e.g. `fillRect(backgroundColor_.get())`) and callbacks are invoked whenever values change. Notice how these callbacks are directly mapped to standard setter methods of the class.

```
class Button
{
public:
    Button(ConfigurationService* service)
        : fontSize_(service, "app.fontSize", 
            [this](int v) { setFontSize(v); })
        , buttonText_(service, "app.button.text") {
        // ...
    }

    void setFontSize(int size) { /* ... */ }

private:
    ConfigurationParameter<int> fontSize_;
    ConfigurationParameter<std::string> buttonText_;
};

class Window
{
public:
    Window(ConfigurationService* service)
        : backgroundColor_(service, "app.mainWindow.bgColor", 
            [this](Color c){ setBackgroundColor(c); })
        , fontSize_(service, "app.fontSize") {
        // ...
        button_ = std::make_unique<Button>(service);
    }

    void setBackgroundColor(Color color) { /* ... */ }

private:
    ConfigurationParameter<Color> backgroundColor_;
    ConfigurationParameter<int> fontSize_;
    std::unique_ptr<Button> button_;
};
```

Lastly, we stick everything together (e.g. in `main`). Create an instance of `ConfigurationService` and then create everything with access to it. With the above implementation it is important, that the `service` outlives all observers, this can be changed easily however.

```
int main()
{
    ConfigurationService service;    
    auto win = std::make_unique<Window>(&service);

    service.readConfigurationFromFile("config.ini");

    // go into main loop
    // change configuration(s) whenever you need
    service.setConfigurationParameter("app.fontSize", "12");
}
```

Due to the observers and update callbacks, entire configuration (or merely single entries) can be changed at any time.

Feel free to play around with the above code [here](http://cpp.sh/6byd)

---

Let me quickly summarize:

- There is no intertwining of classes. `Window` does not need to know anything about the configuration of `Button`.
- It is true that all classes need access to the `ConfigurationService`, but one can easily this by an interface, making the actual implementation interchangeable.
- Implementation effort is mediocre. The only thing you need to extend to support more configuration types is the `fromString` template, but that is needed anyway if you want to parse configurations from text files.
- Configurations can be per class (as in the example) or per object (just pass the configuration key or just a prefix to the class constructor).
- Different classes/objects can hook onto the same configuration entry.
- Configurations can be provided from arbitrary sources. Merely add another function (e.g. `loadConfigurationFromDatabase`) to the `ConfigurationService`, to do so.
- Unknown configuration entries and/or unexpected types can be detected and reported to the user, a log file or somewhere else.
- Configuration can be changed programmatically, if necessary. Add a corresponding method to `ConfigurationService` and the programmatically changed configuration can be written back to file or database at program exit.
- Configurations can be changed during execution (not only at startup).
- Configurable values (`ConfigurationParameter` members) can be used comfortably. This can be improved further by providing a respective cast operator (`operator T() const`).
- The `ConfigurationService` instance must be passed to all classes that need to register something. This can be circumvented using a global or static instance (e.g. as a Singleton), although I am not sure whether this is any better.
- A lot of improvements are possible regarding performance and memory consumption (e.g. converting every parameter only once). See the above as a mere sketch.

Answer (score 0):

I decided that **I prefer the first approach** more, due to the type safety, also I didn't realy like the idea of *every every* object holding a pointer to some Config.

I did also realize that my perception about DI was not quite correct, or at least that there's a better way to implement it in my case.
So, instead of accepting *all* parameters of *all objects down the tree*, a constructor only receives **the direct & required dependencies**. This entirely solves the duplication issue of 1.

This leaves us only with the tight coupling problem - main has to know about virtually everyone. To know how to create a Window, it needs to create a Layout, and Box, and everybody else.

Firstly, I wanted to take this problem somewhere else, so I made a class to create objects for me. Like a factory, but only used to hide dirty stuff from main.
In a `ConfigFactory` now I store all parameters in some way and pass them when I need to construct an object. It is irrelevant how configuration is stored, I decided to have a simple `struct Data` and used PIMPL so that no recompilation of any `ConfigFactory.h`-dependent file  is needed when parameter logic is changed (that's supposed to happen quite often)

Next, I saw how this guy used templates to make a Factory more generic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26950454, but **instead of working with base and derived classes, pointers and dynamic allocation**, I defined a member function which **returns a stack-allocated object** (ideally):

```
template <typename T> T produce() const { return {}; }
```

If there's no specialization of `produce` for the desired type, `T` is default constructed - this way it's more flexible when adding/removing specializations.

I keep `ConfigFactory.h` only this small and free of any `#include`s, so that I do not birng any unneeded dependencies to those who include it.

Now, if I need to have something `produced()`, I include `ConfigFactory.h` and declare a specialization for it. I put its definition in some source file (`ConfigFactory.cpp`) and `produce()` the object using the parameters in `this->data`:

main.cpp:

```
#include "ConfigFactory.h"
#include "Window.h"

template <> Window ConfigFactory::process() const;

int main (int argc, const char** argv) {
    ConfigFactory factory{argc, argv};

    Window window = factory.produce<Window>();
}
```

ConfigFactory.cpp, Window.cpp or whoever knows how to make a Window:

```
template <> Layout ConfigFactory::produce() const;

template <> Window ConfigFactory::produce() const
{
    Window window{produce<Layout>()}; // required dependencies
    window.setPrintFps(data->print_fps); // optional ones
    return window;
}
```

- If I put the `produce()` definitions in the corresponding source files, I have some bad feeling about it - because I define things not declared in the header.
- But if I use `ConfigFactory.h` for the definitions, it gets quite long and heavy as it needs to know about *every* `produce()`able class.

Currently I'm using both and in general it works, but it's not perfect.