# Resolving circular dependencies from inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it not possible to include the baseclass header and have it include all of its subclasses through it?

I seem to have come to an circular dependency with my base class and its subclasses.

From the program entry, I need to initialize one of the subclasses based on user input. I thought I could include the header of the base class which includes the headers of the subclasses:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "baseclass.h"

int main()
{
    ...
}
```

**baseclass.h**

```
#include "sub1.h"

class Base
{
    public:
        int name;
};
```

**sub1.h**

```
#include "baseclass.h"

class Base; // forward declaration

class Sub : public Base
{
    public:
        int age;
};
```

So the dependency is:

`main -> baseclass -> sub1 -> baseclass -> sub1 -> etc...`

If I keep the forward declaration in, `g++ -std=c++11 -o prog *.cpp` throws:

`error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Base'`

Removing:

`error: expected class-name before '{' token {`

Not sure how to resolve this without putting a middle "factory" that includes all the subclass headers which each include the baseclass header.

Comment: @Zeta Header guards are in place

Comment: Why do you include "sub1.h" into "baseclass.h"?

Comment: @geza I was trying to only include the "baseclass.h" into `main.cpp` so that in `main()` I could call `Sub1 S;` without having to include the headers of all the subclasses. If that is not the correct way to accomplish what I want to do, then what perhaps do you recommend?

Comment: Why do you forward declare `Base` and also include? You can't inherit from a forward declaration.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk There is probably a conglomerate of "attempts" wrapped up in that post as I tried (aimlessly from SO searching) to resolve the dependency to achieve my desired goal which was a single include that allowed access to all my subclasses which I thought I could do through including the baseclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `#include "sub1.h"` from `baseclass.h`, and create a separate header file, which includes all the derived classes you need, and include this header file into main.cpp.

Note: this line `class Base; // forward declaration` is not needed.

Comment: Ah, so this is the way to go. Is this standard C++ practice? I come from a Python background where I don't need to do this at all.

Comment: @pstatix: That's one way. The other is not using separate "sub1.h" files, but putting base+all derived classes into one header file. But I'd recommend this approach only if the resulting header file is not too big.

Comment: @pstatix: Note, that it seems weird in the first place, if "baseclass.h" defined all the derived classes. It's name is `baseclass`, so it should only give the definition of `Base`. And then you have a convenience "all_derived.h", which could give all the definitions of derived classes.

Comment: I was trying to avoid having a header that simple contained 6-7 `#include sub_n.h` calls, thought it seemed like a bandaid to the bigger problem. Now it appears that having the "master" inclusion file is the way to resolve this.

Comment: @pstatix: you can have it: you have to put `#include "sub_n.h"` at the end of `baseclass.h` (not at the beginning). But it's a very ugly solution, I don't recommend it, it could generate problems later.

Comment: @pstatix You should learn how preprocessor works. Note that `#include` is not equivalent of python's `import`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `#include "sub1.h"` from `base.h` (also the `class Base` forward declaration). Where you wan't to use `sub` include `sub1.h`, in this case in the main. If you are actually building a bunch of `sub` type child classes then in all likelihood you will implement something to create them correctly anyway. That something would probably be a [factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120768/how-to-implement-the-factory-method-pattern-in-c-correctly). It will look something like this:

```
// ClassFactory.h
#include "sub1.h"
#include "sub2.h"
...
#include "subN.h"

std::unique_ptr<Base> createClass(std::string name) {

    if (name == "sub1")
        return std::unique_ptr<Base>(new sub1());
    if (name == "sub2")
        return std::unique_ptr<Base>(new sub1());
    ...
    return nullptr;
}
```

And your `main` will include and use this file:

```
#include "ClassFactory.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<Base> myClass = createClass(argv[1])
```

**Big note:** *All pseudo code*.

Then you will have solved the problem of creating a complex set of child classes at runtime and your problem of how to include all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `base.h` to include `sub1.h`, that is possible only **after** the definition of `class Base` :

```
#ifndef BASE_H_
#define BASE_H_

class Base
{
    public:
        int name;
};

#include "sub1.h"
#endif
```

It's obvious that this removes the need for a forward declaration of `Base`; at the point of inclusion it's fully defined.