# Function that returns just the constructor

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>


struct something{
    int i;

    something(int i) : i(i) {}
};

class otherthing {

    otherthing(){}

    static something foo(int value)
    {
        return { value };
    }
};
```

In this example what the foo function returns? Am I understand correctly that it creates an object on the heap and returns a pointer? Is this considered bad style? Or is it ok for structs and not classes?

I can feel that it might be a stupid question but I tried to google it and I could not find the answer. I apologize in advance if this is dumb.

Comment: Where do you see a pointer? Pointers don't appear out of thin air. Somewhere, somehow, a pointer needs to be declared. Where is it?

Comment: I suspect you're getting confused with a [factory function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120768/how-to-implement-the-factory-method-pattern-in-c-correctly) which typically uses `new` in which case it would return a pointer. But you have `otherthing::foo()` returning an instance of `something` on the stack.

Comment: You said it returns a `something` by value, so it does. It just uses [copy list initialisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) to do so.

Comment: Here the `foo` class static function is a *factory* function that creates a `something`.  But if the object produced was *polymorphic*, then it would really need to return a `something*` or better `std::unique_ptr<something>` so that polymorphism will work.  Not the case here, but that's one reason a pointer would be returned instead of return-by-value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In this example what the foo function returns?

Object of type `something`, initialized with value `value`.

> Am I understand correctly that it creates an object on the heap and returns a pointer?

No. It creates an object with automatic lifetime (typically associated with stack memory). It returns that object and no pointer.

> Is this considered bad style?

It's quite useless in this example, but in general this approach is called [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). It allows you to separate creation of object from other logic, and that would be good style actually.

> Or is it ok for structs and not classes?

The only difference between `struct` and `class` in C++ is the default access modifier. In `struct` member are by default `public`, in `class` members are by default `private`.

Comment: also inheritance is default private / public.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 for "members" read "members and bases"

Answer (score 1):

> Am I understand correctly that it creates an object on the heap and returns a pointer?

No, it does not return a pointer, it returns an instance of `something` with automatic storage duration (which is commonly allocated on the stack) which for the return will utilize [copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127)

> Or is it ok for structs and not classes?

A `struct` and a `class` only differ in the default access modifier, besides that there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ (unlike C#) classes and structs are identical but for one tiny detail: the default access level for a class is private; for a struct it's public.

In your example, a `something` object is created on the stack in `foo`. When `foo` is called, e.g.

```
something s = otherthing.foo();
```

then the object is copied into `s` on the stack.

No pointers are involved.