# Initialize class member to different derived classes in a hierarchy

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, initialization, initializer-list

I have a class `baseNoCrtpIterator` that holds one member `baseNoCrtp _base`, among others.
Class `baseNoCrtp` has several simply derived classes `derived[n]NoCrtp`, where `[n]` denotes a number 1,2,... These classes do not add any data members to `baseNoCrtp`, only some functionality.

I want that, during construction of a `baseNoCrtpIterator`, member `_base` is assigned one of `derived[n]NoCrtp`, depending on another value `dclass` passed to the constructor.

**Is that possible?**

I tried a **constructor** like

```
baseNoCrtpIterator::baseNoCrtpIterator(const int dclass) :
    _base(dclass)       // Point #8
{
    if (dclass == 0) {
        derived1NoCrtp* d1n = new derived1NoCrtp(0);
        _base = *d1n;        // Point #9
    }
    else if (dclass == 1) {
        derived2NoCrtp* d2n = new derived2NoCrtp(1);
        _base = *d2n;
    } else {
        cout << "Unknown derived class: " << dclass << endl;
        throw runtime_error("Unknown derived class");
    }
};
```

This doesn't work, and I probably have to fix #8 (I guess I have to remove it from the initializer list), and #9, since I don't have `operator=` (I could write it, but I guess it doesn't solve my problem).

**Note**:
I guess CRTP *might* be an alternative.
But I see a couple of problems:

1. All uses of `baseNoCrtpIterator` have to be replaced by `baseNoCrtpIterator<T>`. Thus, downstream, all functions, classes, etc., that use `baseNoCrtpIterator` will have to be "templetized".
   This means huge changes in existing code.
2. I would not be able to hold all objects of class `baseNoCrtp` and derived in a single container. That is part of the changes mentioned above.

---

**TL;DR**

I have two hierarchies of (base + n simply derived) classes.
One is a "*main*" hierarchy, and the other is an "*iterator*" hierarchy, meant to iterate over the main.

The base class for the *iterators* refers to the base class for the *main* in #1

```
class baseNoCrtpIterator {
public:
    baseNoCrtpIterator(const baseNoCrtp& base, const int dclass);
    virtual ~baseNoCrtpIterator() {};

    const baseNoCrtp& operator*() const { return *operator->(); };
    const baseNoCrtp* operator->() const { return &_base; };
private:
    baseNoCrtp _base;   // Point #1
    int _index;
};
```

and its **constructor** is

```
baseNoCrtpIterator::baseNoCrtpIterator(const structure& s, const int dclass) :
    _base(s, dclass),
    _index(0) { };
```

where `dclass` indicates the derived class of `_base` (that is not enough, as will be shown later).
The derived iterator classes are like this (`derived1...` is associated with `dclass=0`, and so on)

```
class derived1NoCrtpIterator : public baseNoCrtpIterator {         // derived1...
public:
    derived1NoCrtpIterator(const baseNoCrtp& base) : baseNoCrtpIterator(base, 0) {};   // ... dclass=0
    virtual ~derived1NoCrtpIterator() {};

    const derived1NoCrtp& operator*() { return *operator->(); }
    const derived1NoCrtp* operator->() {                             // Point #2
        const baseNoCrtp* bnp = baseNoCrtpIterator::operator->();    // Point #3
        return static_cast<const derived1NoCrtp*>(bnp);              // Point #4
    }
};
```

The problem is when using something like

```
for (derived1NoCrtpIterator d1ni(sconst); ...) {
    const derived1NoCrtp& d1nr = *d1ni;   // Point #5
    ...
```

Point #5 leads to #2.
In #3 we extract a pointer to member `baseNoCrtp`.
But then the `static_cast` downcast in #4 is undefined behavior.
This could be solved if the **constructor** `baseNoCrtpIterator::baseNoCrtpIterator` assigned to `baseNoCrtp` objects of the derived classes `derived1NoCrtpIterator`, etc., instead of the base class.

I tried to replace the **constructor** with something like

```
baseNoCrtpIterator::baseNoCrtpIterator(const structure& s, const int dclass) :
    _base(s, dclass),        // Point #8
    _index(0) {
    if (dclass == 0) {
        derived1NoCrtp* d1n = new derived1NoCrtp(s, 0);
        _base = *d1n;        // Point #9
    }
    else if (dclass == 1) {
        derived2NoCrtp* d2n = new derived2NoCrtp(s, 1);
        _base = *d2n;
    } else {
        cout << "Unknown derived class: " << dclass << endl;
        throw runtime_error("Unknown derived class");
    }
};
```

This doesn't work, and I probably have to fix #8 (I guess I have to remove it from the initializer list), and #9, since I don't have `operator=` (I could write it, but I guess it doesn't solve my problem).

**How can I achieve this assignment to `_base` of objects of derived classes, depending on `dclass`?**

Since this is a boiled down example of a very large code that I have to fix,
I am in principle not interested in other methods that require extensive modifications of the code.
For instance, if CRTP *might* be a solution, it probably involves huge changes.
I know the current way might be a somewhat contrived form of iterating the main hierarchy, but this is what I received.

---

The "main" classes are (here it is not relevant what `structure` is):

```
class baseNoCrtp {
public:
    baseNoCrtp(const structure& s, const int dclass) :
        _structure(s), _derivedClass(dclass) { };
    virtual ~baseNoCrtp() {};
public:
    int getDerivedClass() const { return _derivedClass; }
    const structure& getStructure() const { return _structure; };
protected:
    const structure& _structure;
private:
    friend class baseNoCrtpIterator;
    int _derivedClass;
};

class derived1NoCrtp : public baseNoCrtp {
public:
    derived1NoCrtp(const structure& s) : baseNoCrtp(s, 0) {};
    virtual ~derived1NoCrtp() {};
    // Add whatever extra methods
};
```

Comment: The type of `_base` is `baseNoCrtp` - and nothing else. You can't stuff a derived type in there. You need a reference or pointer type to get virtual dispatch. Or make that type a template parameter.

Comment: This is really a case for a Factory Pattern. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120768/how-to-implement-the-factory-method-pattern-in-c-correctly

Comment: @Mat - I made a few tests and I was coming to that same conclusion...

Comment: @NathanielJohnson - Will check in more detail whether that applies to my case.

Answer (score 0):

It *seems* this is not possible, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70989229/initialize-class-member-to-different-derived-classes-in-a-hierarchy?noredirect=1#comment125494932_70989229).

The "workaround" is to change the type of member `_base`, to `baseNoCrtp*`, so it can point to objects of any derived class.